# If this is a prison for the believer and paradise for the non believer, why even bring a child into the world?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, islamic-scholar

I have a moral and ethical dilemma. I believe that the world is a cold and cruel place to be in. Had I myself had the option, I'd have rather my mother had me aborted so that I never experienced any of this. I cannot commit suicide so I'm pretty much stuck on this floating rock on Earth until my time finally comes.

Being 26 many people I know are getting married and having children. I say "why?" Why bring an innocent child into the world just to make them live in this jungle? This is paradise for the nonbeliever and a prison for the believer. Why subject an innocent life to endure these horrible tests of faith until they depart from the world?

I believe that in my not having children I will potentially save hundreds or even thousands of future descendants from having to go through with living in this prison. Is this haram?

Comment: Of relevance to your question: (1) [Is it haram not to have children?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/), (2) [Is it obligatory in islam to continue to have more children when you can't provide for your existing children?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/), (3) [What justifies having children if there is a possibility that they will suffer eternally in the afterlife?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43044/), and (4) [What is the wisdom behind the importance of getting married and have children?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/).

Answer (score 2):

Why do people work hard to achieve a particular goal? They may not enjoy all the hard work they put in but they will enjoy the fruits of their labour.

Similarly if you know what is waiting for you in the next life then the temporarily struggle and pain we undergo in this life will certainly be wothwhile at the end

What are a few years on earth compared to eternity in paradise, bare in mind that this life is short and it will pass in a blink of an eye:

> Allah extends provision for whom He wills and restricts [it]. And they
>   rejoice in the worldly life, while the worldly life is not, compared
>   to the Hereafter, except **[brief]** enjoyment. [Quran 13:26]

Bare in mind that any pain experienced in this life is a means of expiating sin:

> It was narrated in al-Saheehayn that the Prophet (peace and blessings
>   of Allaah be upon him) said: “No tiredness, exhaustion, worry, grief,
>   distress or harm befalls a believer in this world, not even a thorn
>   that pricks him, but Allaah expiates some of his sins thereby.”
>   (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5210; Muslim, 4670)

So rest assured that any struggle faced will surely be generously rewarded:

If you were shown paradise and the road to it, paradise being the most beautiful place you could ever be and the road being rocky, painful and depressing but it is short would you not travel on that road to reach paradise?

> The Prophet (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said, “When Allah created
>   Paradise and Hell, He sent Jibreel to Paradise and said, ‘Look at it
>   and at what I have prepared for its people therein.’ So he went and
>   looked at it and at what Allah had prepared for its people therein.
>   Then he went back to Him and said, ‘By Your Glory, no one will hear of
>   it but he will enter it.’ Then He commanded that it should be
>   surrounded with difficult things. Then He said, ‘Go back and look at
>   what I have prepared for its people therein.’ He went back and saw
>   that it was surrounded with difficult things. He came back and said,
>   ‘By Your Glory, I am afraid that no one will enter it.’ Allah said,
>   ‘Go and look at Hell and see what I have prepared for its people
>   therein.’  [He saw it] with parts of it consuming other parts. He came
>   back and said, ‘By Your Glory, no one who hears of it will enter it.’
>   So Allah commanded that it should be surrounded with desires. Then he
>   said, ‘Go back to it.’ So he went back, then he said, ‘By Your Glory,
>   I am afraid that no one will be saved from it and that all will enter
>   it.’” [Sunan al-Tirmidhi (2560)]

I understand your point of view as it was always something I wondered about and to summaraise my conclusion in two points:

- AFAIK it is not sinful not and not obligatory to have an offspring.
- By not having children you might denying them the opportunity to gain a place in paradise

Comment: *Would you want to deny your children the opportunity of being with you in paradise?* - this dismisses the fact that the person maybe want to have children in paradise.

Comment: "Would you want to deny your children the opportunity of being with you in paradise?" My answer is I just do not want to cause any more unnecessary suffering on this Earth. Many have came before me but I feel great honor in knowing that it is up to me to stop this vicious cycle of endless suffering. I will be the end of my clan and I'm doing this for a greater purpose, to free those from prison of Earth. It is the only way to commit suicide without committing suicide so to speak. I find it a great honor and this will be my life's mission to carry out my plan.

Answer (score -1):

Some facts you mentioned are correct, every new human being that enters the life, he also enters in a very serious EXAM/TEST that may lead to fatal outcomes.

After the life on earth, there are only two scenarios for humans (descendants from Adam and Hawa).

Many known scholars didn’t have sons or even get married, that’s not the real problem, but having doubts contradicts with Iman (Faith) or thinking that Allah is not fair or wise.

Judgment day is something that proves the wisdom of God. If all the humans die without being resurrected for judgment then bad and good people will be treated similarly!